# Trying to set minWorkerThreads , minIoThreads

Tags: multithreading

I am trying to set the minWorkerThreads and minIoThreads

in order to tune it I understood it can be done via :

1. global aspx when server start :
   int completionPortThreads = Int32.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Service.CompletionPortThreads"] ?? "20");
   int workerThreads = Int32.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Service.WorkerThreads"] ?? "20");
   bool setThreadPoolWorked = ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(workerThreads, completionPortThreads);

from XML :

2.  machine config

processModel autoConfig="false" minWorkerThreads="100" minIoThreads="100"

it seems the iis is not taking the correct data or change the threads as he like. i tried to set in machine.config :  autoconfig=false , but still it does not work properly.

any suggestions ?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1872

Comment: thank u ! i am running on prem and not on the cloud anf for now without .net core...it is iis config and i tried all of the configuration but it is not working as expected....